# System.Speech not recognized

Tags: c#, speech-to-text

I am using C# 2010 Express, and I want to do speech recognition. However, when I type the following at the beginning of my file:

```
using System.Speech;
```

`System.Speech` is not recognized. Just to be sure, I installed the Speech SDK from Microsoft, but saw no difference.

I am using the .NET 4.0 Client Profile framework, which should work fine, I think.

What should I do to resolve this? Is it a limitation of C# Express?

Comment: Ensure you have added a reference to `System.Speech`.

Comment: Go to References in Solution Explorer, then right-click on it then Add Reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add a reference to it. Go to the solution explorer:

[image]

Then right-click the references item and choose add reference. Make sure you are on the tab .Net in the window that pops up. Scroll down until you see System.Speech.

[image]

Select it and click OK. Now it will recognize speech.

Comment: WOW THANKS !!
Me to i like to help people with programming (on other languages), but you do it with images and good excelent THANKS !!

I was used to older version of visual studio, i didnt knew it was there, it always was somewhere in the menus. i was just thinking since i couldnt drop it on the form it was a c# express limitation
Oh really thank full

I can now continue on writing the program, i want to do some fuzy logic / or / genetic coding to evolve random sound data, to evolve to recognized audio samples.. well its partly research for my own (not university related)

Answer (score 0):

It support in .NET 4.0 and higher versions..you need to explicitly include that namespace from Add Reference .NET tab